# Method collect on Scala 2.7

Tags: list, scala

I'm looking for a `collect` method in scala 2.7 but I can't seem to find an applicable call. Is there something equivalent to `collect` that I can use in scala?

To be clear I'm looking to filter elements from a list and map those filtered to a new type.

Comment: Note that `filterMap` has been renamed `collect`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` (the full method signature in 2.7 is `def  flatMap[B](f : (A) => Iterable[B]) : List[B]` ). It is declared on both `Iterable` and `Iterator` (with slightly different signatures):

```
scala> val l = List("1", "Hello", "2")
l: List[java.lang.String] = List(1, Hello, 2)

scala> val ints = l.flatMap { s => try { Some(s.toInt) } catch { case _ => None } }
ints: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

In the above example I'm taking advantage of an explicit conversion `option2iterable` in `Predef`. It's declared in 2.8 on `TraversableLike`:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => Traversable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

Comment: I imagine that this creates more objects than `collect` due to all the wrapping in `Some`. Apart from this is there any other difference between this use of `flatMap` and `collect`?

Answer (score 7):

Using `flatMap`/`Option`, as described by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbowlakes) is the way I do it usually, but there is a more involved alternative that is, sometimes, more pleasing to the eyes:

```
class Filter[A](f: Any => Option[A]) {
  def unapply(a: Any) = f(a)
}

object Filter {
  def apply[A](f: Any => Option[A]) = new Filter(f)
}

val evens = Filter {
  case n: Int if n % 2 == 0 => Some(n)
  case _ => None
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> for (evens(n) <- List.range(0,10)) yield n
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: You can call me *Chris*, Daniel!

Comment: Or the one-liner: `for (i <- 1 to 10 if i % 2 == 0) yield i * 2`

Comment: @retronym True enough, though there are certain pattern matches which are not possible using a filter. For instance (perhaps, uniquely), type checking.

Comment: Technically it can still be done, although it's not particularly intuitive: `for { a@(x: Int) <- Seq(1, "1", 2, "2") if a % 2 == 0} yield a`. As you know, #900 prevents `for { x: Int <- ...`. Oddly, `for { a@(_: Int) <-` doesn't work.

Comment: I never considered that alternative. I wouldn't have expected it to work either. Learn something every day. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> List(-1,-2, 1,2,3).filter{i => (i % 2) == 0}.map{i => i / 2} 

line10: scala.List[scala.Int] = List(-1,1)
```

You need to seperate out the two calls

From [a very useful blog](http://blog.lostlake.org/index.php?/archives/41-Scala-Idioms,-Step-1,-Lists-and-Maps.html)

Comment: You don't need to separate out the calls at all